# thick box is not working in chrome

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, thickbox

i'm using thickbox in my webpage

it's working well in firfox , ie but not working in google chrome it shows error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   file:///W:/www/pennyauction/home_page/site/flyout.html?height=315&width=185&inlineId=myOnPageContent&random=1296046181308. Origin null is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Any idea about this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome has a design policy that forbids you from using XMLHTTPRequest to load local files. Firefox does not have this policy.

Presumably you are developing on your local machine for testing purposes and will upload your files to a real server later.

The best solution for testing is to run a lightweight HTTP server on your local machine. A slightly hacky workaround is to open Chrome with the command `chrome --allow-file-access-from-files`, which allows you to do local AJAX temporarily.

Comment: thanks for answer.  how to fix this issue, what is this mean "chrome --allow-file-access-from-files"

Comment: @gowri Start Chrome using that command. If you are on Windows, just type it into the search box in the Start menu and press return.

Comment: @gowri Possibly not. I agree that on my Linux installation with Chromium, I get the same error. Possibly this option has been disabled. My advice would be to install a lightweight server, e.g. [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/).